# ParseSwift.ParseError.Code.internalServer -> bad key in untransform: _batchSize

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, parse-server

I am working on an iOS app, using ParseSwift. The following function was pretty much working until yesterday.

The relevant code is as follows:

```
func handleTapEvent() {
    ......
    print(#function)
    ......
    do {MyCollection.query().find() {
            result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let items):
                // items is of type [MyCollection].
                ......
                print("Number of items found : \(items.count)")
                var actualCount = 0
                for item in items {
                    ......
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error in \(#function): \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
    ......
}
```

And now for some reason that I can't figure out, it does no longer work.

The error message I get in Xcode (12.5) is:

```
Error in handleTapEvent(): 
    ParseError(code: ParseSwift.ParseError.Code.internalServer, 
               message: "bad key in untransform: _batchSize")
```

I can't find any significant help from the net. Has anyone got an idea of what may be going on?

Comment: Do you get this error when running the find operation? Would you mind to share the error stack? Also could you check if you have in your collection this `_batchSize` field set to any of your objects?

Comment: @Davi_Macêdo. Yes I do. The execution flow runs into the .failure branch (where I get the error) instead of running into the .success branch as it did up to recently. Since the error shown in the post is the only thing I can see I don't know what else to share. Or let me know what you mean by "to share the error stack". Beside, I checked for _batchSize as you suggest. And indeed, it appears on two objects in a collection of about 50. Does that make sense to you? And what should I do? Remove it? Even more important, why did it appear in the first place?

Comment: Looking closer at the records, those with _batchSize have a bunch of unexpected fields following it. I don't know where that comes from. Maybe related to something I did with mongo shell. But what I know is I do not expect them here.

Comment: It was probably something you did directly on mongodb. I am not sure though. Anyways, I believe you can delete these objects (make a copy of them before deleting) and give it a try to see if the problem is fixed.

Comment: It doesn't seem I can just delete the fields. I should try to make a copy of the object, taking only the fields I want and then delete the old one. I'll try that.

Comment: @Davi_Macêdo. Finally it works. I was able to remove the the records with _batchSize and create new records with the same relevant data. It is still a mystery though as why this thing appeared.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. Let me know in the case it shows up again and we can try to figure out how to reproduce.

Comment: Yes. I must be somehow related to something I did using mongo shell. But that's all I can guess.